# sklearn: vectorizing in cross validation for text classification

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a question about using cross validation in text classification in sklearn. It is problematic to vectorize all data before cross validation, because the classifier would have "seen" the vocabulary occurred in the test data. Weka has filtered classifier to solve this problem. What is the sklearn equivalent for this function? I mean for each fold, the feature set would be different because the training data are different.

Comment: I think this question may have a better reception on the Stack Exchange machine learning and statistics site named "Cross Validated."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Clarification: it is not off topic because this question is particularly for CV for text classification in sklearn. Numerical data wouldn't have this problem because the feature set is fixed for any fold, but it is different for every fold in text classification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scikit-learn solution to this problem is to cross-validate a `Pipeline` of estimators, e.g.:

```
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> clf = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer()), ('svm', LinearSVC())])
```

`clf` is now a composite estimator that does feature extraction and SVM model fitting. Given a list of documents (i.e. an ordinary Python `list` of string) `documents` and their labels `y`, calling

```
>>> cross_val_score(clf, documents, y)
```

will do feature extraction in each fold separately so that each of the SVMs knows only the vocabulary of its (k-1) folds training set.

Comment: Thanks very much! I tested your solution, which did report different accuracy numbers compared to the no-pipeline approach. Is there any way to print out the vocabulary size for each fold, just to verify? I printed out the feature set size for "clf" and the number is the same as what I got from the no-pipeline approach.

Comment: @user3466018 Not out of the box, but you can implement a no-op transformer that prints `X.shape[1]` and stack that into the pipeline. (Or implement a custom scorer, or hack the vectorizer code to report this.)