# cross validation and text categorization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have the same question which has been asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672436/sklearn-vectorizing-in-cross-validation-for-text-classification):

I have a question about using cross validation in text classification in `sklearn`. It is problematic to vectorize all data before cross validation, because the classifier would have "seen" the vocabulary occurred in the test data. `Weka` has filtered classifier to solve this problem. What is the `sklearn` equivalent for this function? I mean for each fold, the feature set would be different because the training data are different.

However, because I am doing lots of processing for the data between the categorization step and the classification step, I cannot use pipelines ... and was trying to implement the cross validation by my self as an outer loop for the whole process ... any guidance on this as I am fairly new to both python and sickitlearn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using the cross-validation iterator as an outer loop is a good idea and a starting point that would make your steps clear and readable:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
X = np.array(["Science today", "Data science", "Titanic", "Batman"]) #raw text
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2]) #categories e.g., Science, Movies
kf = KFold(y.shape[0], n_folds=2)
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    x_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index] 
    x_test, y_test = X[test_index], y[test_index]
    #Now continue with your pre-processing steps..
```

Comment: Thanks .. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just adding updated code!



`from sklearn.model_selection import KFold`
`import numpy as np`
`X = np.array(["Science today", "Data science", "Titanic", "Batman"]) #raw text`
`y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2]) #categories e.g., Science, Movies`

`kf = KFold(n_splits=2)`

`for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):`
    `x_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index] `
    `x_test, y_test = X[test_index], y[test_index] `

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing the meaning of your question and am unfamiliar with Weka, but you can pass the vocabulary as a dictionary into the vectorizer you use in sklearn. Here is an example that will skip the word 'second' in the test set, using only features from the train set.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

train_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
train = [
    'this is the first',
    'set of documents'
    ]

train_matrix = train_vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
train_vocab = train_vectorizer.vocabulary_

test = [
    'this is the second',
    'set of documents'
    ]

test_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=train_vocab)
test_matrix = test_vectorizer.fit_transform(test)

print(train_vocab)
print(train_matrix.toarray())
print('\n')
print(test_vectorizer.vocabulary_)
print(test_matrix.toarray())
```

Also note that you could use your own processing and/or tokenization processes in the vectorizer like:

```
def preprocessor(string):
    #do logic here

def tokenizer(string):
    # do logic here

from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
clf = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer(processor=preprocessor, tokenizer=tokenizer)), ('svm', LinearSVC())])
```

Comment: I am doing some sampling between the vectorising and the classification step and because of that I wasn't able to put it in a pipeline .. On the same time I want to do cross validation which needs to have a pipeline or , as a solution , I was thinking of doing an outer loop which partition the data for cross validation then I go to process/classify each data on the cv iterations